# Serving Svelte MPA with nested components via go webserver

Tags: go, svelte, svelte-component

I want create a multi-page application where individual sites are constructed from Svelte components. The pages are constructed from a template engine and served via a go server.

I followed a written & [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4YnzS14UYcQ&), that instructed me to add the customElement compiler option, modified `main.js` to import the respective svelte components, setup go server and template engine.

```
svelte({
    compilerOptions: {
        // enable run-time checks when not in production
        dev: !production,
        customElement: true,
    }
}),
```

This is the index.html

```
{{define "body"}}
    <td-explorer></td-explorer>
{{end}}
```

Here is the Svelte Component:

```
// Explorer.svelte
<script>
  import {Tile} from "carbon-components-svelte";
</script>

<svelte:options tag="td-explorer"/>
<div>
  <p>asdf</p>
  <Tile></Tile>
</div>
```

Here is the handler that renders the template:

```
func IndexPage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    base := filepath.Join("./backend/server/webserver/templates", "base.html")
    index := filepath.Join("./backend/server/webserver/templates", "index.html")

    tmpl, _ := template.ParseFiles(base, index)
    tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "base", nil)
}
```

The site is served as expected. All static resources are reachable.[image]

The problem is that as soon as the customElement component `td-explorer` contains another component (such as `<Tile>` which is part of a ui library), the server merely shows a blank page. If I remove this nested component, our `td-explorer` gets rendered as expected, showing 'asdf'.

Answer (score 0):

I use this one [Svelte-MPA](https://github.com/kokizzu/svelte-mpa)

So any server-side language (for example using [ZTemplate](https://github.com/kokizzu/gotro/tree/master/Z)) will inject the json for generated html from Svelte if need initial data, if not, you can just create a .svelte file (page) and it would generate html on build/watch, for any other .svelte file that started with underscore or in folder that starts with underscore it would became a svelte component that can be imported by other svelte page.

So to do this, you just need to inject on page level instead of component level, then import and use the component.

for example:

```
<script>
  importy MyComponent from './_myComponent.svelte'
  let myData = [/* myData */]
<script>

{#each myData as row}
  <MyComponent row={row} />
{/each}
```

the server side render can be something like this:

```
ctx.Render("myPage.html", M.SX{ // map[string]any
   myData: []MyStruct{ {A: 1, B: 2}, {A: 3, B: 4} },
})
```

where `myPage.html` is generated from `myPage.svelte`

the example can be found here: https://github.com/kokizzu/sveltefiber/blob/main/main.go#L26

or more complex example: https://github.com/kokizzu/street/blob/master/presentation/web_static.go#L25